# Statistical analysis for non-human experiments

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I am running an experiment where no humans are involved. My mobile robot performs a tracking task (following a line in the ground) under 5 different conditions (different control variables). I evaluate the tracking error **at each instant** and then I average it over time, so that I have, for each condition, a MEAN ERROR $\pm$ S.D.

How can I tell if one condition is better than another one? I can see if the MEAN ERROR is lower, but if both have high S.D.s they may have been much closer than I think.

Can I treat each instant as a subject and apply a standard stat analysis (e.g. repeated-measure ANOVA across the 5 conditions)?

Comment: @Claudio If both the account from which this question was posted and the account from which it was edited belong to the same person, you should probably seek to merge your accounts. The fact that the gravatar looks different suggests they're under different email accounts (which implies it might not be the same person), but if they're both one person (i.e. you), it would be best to stick with one account (not least, to avoid accusations you may be voting for yourself, for example).